# Does filtering a view in SQL Server execute on all records before filtering?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Out of curiosity, if you filter a view, does the view return the full view results then filter down?

For example,
SELECT * FROM VW_INVOICES
WHERE DATE = GETDATE()

(SELECT * for just the example)
Does the view execute on all records, then filters on the date clause?  Or does the query include that clause in the initial execution of the dataset?

Comment: The code for the view is effectively pasted into the query as a derived subquery, then the whole query is optimized in one go. A predicate such as what you show will probably pushed down into the view's scope in most circumstances. See linked post

Comment: Depends on the view. If  your view has subqueries or other complex stuff, sometimes whole view has to be materialized before processing the WHERE. You can see the query plan for your query to understand what actually happens for a particular query

Comment: Consider Table-Valued Functions.  You can pass parameters and therefore more performant than a full view